# Banco de dados pré-escrito (Phonegap/Cordova + sqlite)

Tags: banco-de-dados, apache-cordova, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um App utilizando Phonegap/Cordova e Sqlite, porém juntamente com o aplicativo é necessário ir um banco de dados contendo aproximadamente 50MB de informações de texto. Estou usando o app "Phonegap" do android pra testar a aplicação, mas eu não faço a minima ideia de como colocar as informações(50MB) de texto no banco de dados sqlite(plugin).

Quando eu instalei o plugin (Sqlite) não encontrei nenhum arquivo de banco de dados onde eu pudesse abri-lo com um gerenciador e inserir as informações manualmente para que quando fizesse o "Buld" ele ficasse no App.

Faz 2 semanas que não tenho conseguido encontrar essa informação, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Você quer um SGDB para o sqlite? Proccure por sqlite studio ou databasebrowser. Existe varios que são compativeis com sqlite.

Comment: Intendo, mas é o seguinte meu amigo, como eu localizo o arquivo do banco de dados dentro do projeto Cordova/Pronegap?
O arquivo fica dentro de qual pasta? e qual é a extenção dele?

Answer (score 0):

Não posso comentar depois edito, caso precise.
Normalmente depois de você compilar o projeto e se você estiver criando o banco de dados SQLite ao iniciar o aplicativo, o caminho para o banco de dados após criado ficaria parecido com esse em seu dispositivo.

> /data/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/databases/MyDatabase.db

Para saber o caminho aonde seu app foi instalado basta digitar isso no terminal (Linux). com seu dispostivo em modo debug e conectado ao pc é claro.

Para acessar o dispostivo via terminal:

> adb shell

Retornará o caminho em que o app esta instalado:

> run-as "com.nome.nomeapp"

Depois basta entrar na pasta /databases e la estará seu arquivo ".db".

Apesar de achar que não seja necessário incluir manualmente pelo que entendi.
você pode criar um script de inserção para quando o app for iniciado pela primeira vez ele insira esses dados na tabela.